# Two possible answers for x

Tags: logarithms

I was trying to solve a question on maxima-minima and I finally ended up getting this equation:
             $$\ln\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)=1$$

If I take anti-log on both sides I get $\frac{1}{x}=e$ and therefore $x=\frac{1}{e}$.

But if I expand the log as $\ln(\frac{1}{x})=\ln(1)-\ln(x)=1$, I get $x=e$.

Why are there two possible answers? Am I doing anything terribly wrong? Please correct me.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh....that's the greatest careless mistake that I have done in my life.....thanks for correcting me...

Comment: $-\ln(x)=1$ means $\ln(x)=-1$, so the answer is still $-e$.

Comment: If that is your greatest careless mistake, you have a ways to go to be competitive.

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions are consistent: Note, we are subtracting $\ln 1 - \ln x = 0 - \ln x = -\ln x$. So, expanding as you did in the second case, but correcting for the sign error:
$$\ln\left(\frac 1x\right) = \ln (1) - \ln (x) = 1 \iff - \ln x = 1 \iff \ln x = -1 \implies x = e^{-1} = \dfrac 1e$$

Answer (score 0):

You lost a negative sign in passing from $\ln(1)-\ln(x)=1$  You should get $-\ln(x)=1$ which has solution $1/e$

Answer (score 0):

$ x = e $ actually does not satisfy the equation

$$\ln(1) - \ln(x) = 1$$

because $ \ln(1) - \ln(x) = \ln(1) - \ln(e) = 0 - 1 = -1 \neq 1$.

You are correct with the first solution $ x = \frac{1}{e} $ but it turns out to be the ''only'' solution.